# android get current location failed

Tags: android, dictionary, location

I wan't to get my current location,but in most phones it's failed.
Next is mycode:

```
public Location getLocation(Context context)
{
    LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = locMan
        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location == null)
    {
        location = locMan
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }

    return location;
}
```

Comment: It *failed* thats **VERY** helpful.

Comment: Need more info. Have you added the required permissions to the manifest?

Comment: do u have any error.. if so paste stacktrace

Comment: I have add all need permissions to the manifest.This function works sometimes,but sometimes failed.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this...might be possible that locationmanager doesn't have your last location

/**
     * this function is used to instantiate location manager and bind it to GPS provider.
     * location manager will request for location updates after every 5 minutes. 
     */

```
private void subscribeToLocationUpdates() {
      this.lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
      this.lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,5000, 0, this);
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location != null){

        //make use of this location

    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all - did you set the right permission? The location permissions are implicit - so if you request fine location, you'll get coarse, too.

Did you follow [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) guide(s) for getting your location?

Normally you don't set up a LocationService each time you want to get the current Location, too. Did you try to request location updates for yourself?

There is too less code and the question is too unspecified to really help you, sorry.

Comment: I just wan't to get the current location,and don't need to get the updated location,is there some easy function get the location?

Answer (score 0):

Add the Permission  ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION  in the Manifest file